# How to change an AWS dynamoDB table field automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am developing a public event app using AWS amplify, data are stored in a dynamoDB table and connection between data and app is done with appsync/graphQl,
an authenticated user can create a public event, but if no one is interested in this event, after 24 hours the status of the event must be switched to 'Expired' and a notification will be sent to the owner of event,
Since I am newbie to AWS and amplify, is Lambda function is best service to implement this feature and How?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to change some attributes on DynamoDB every 24 hours, try to use AWS EventBridge with the scheduled event, the event will trigger a Lambda function and pull data from DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

As referred in the comment you can incorporate a scheduler to check periodically for outdated events. If you find those events update the attribute.

You can further add a DynamoDB Stream to listen on that events which have changed the state to `Expired` and process your logic downstream (sending notifications).